# Unable to install pyglet on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pyglet

I'm trying to install pyglet on my Mac using`pip install pyglet`

But I got:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
root=options.root_path,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 646, in install
**kwargs
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 803, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 998, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 339, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 310, in clobber
ensure_dir(destdir)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 71, in ensure_dir
os.makedirs(path)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet'
```

Can anyone figure out what the problem is and fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: maybe try `sudo pip install pyglet`

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot :)